# Derivative of basis vector in terms of Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, mathematics

I would like to derive the formula

$$\partial_{c}\vec{e}^{\,a}=-\Gamma_{bc}^{a}\vec{e}^{\,b}$$

where $\vec{e}_{a}$ are the basis vectors on a manifold.

In the lecture, we did it in the following way:

$$0=\partial_{c}(\delta_{b}^{a})=\partial_{c}(\vec{e}^{\,a}\cdot\vec{e}_{\,b})=\vec{e}_{\,b}\cdot\partial_{c}\vec{e}^{\,a}+\underbrace{\vec{e}^{\,a}\cdot\partial_{c}\vec{e}_{\,b}}_{=\Gamma_{bc}^{a}}$$

and therefore

$$\vec{e}_{\,b}\cdot\partial_{c}\vec{e}^{\,a}=-\Gamma_{bc}^{a}$$

Up to here I can follow. Then it is stated: "Multipliying with $\vec{e}^{\,b}$ yields the result", but I can't unterstand how.

If I multiply by $\vec{e}^{\,b}$ and then sum over $b$, we get

$$\vec{e}^{\,b}\cdot (\vec{e}_{\,b}\cdot\partial_{c}\vec{e}^{\,a})=-\Gamma_{bc}^{a}\vec{e}^{\,b}$$

How can we simplify the LHS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual *definition* of the Christoffel symbols  is
$$\nabla_\mu {\bf e}_\nu = {\bf e}_\sigma {\Gamma^\sigma}_{\nu\mu}
$$
where $\nabla_\mu $ is a covaraint derivative and the ${\bf e}_\mu$ are basis vectors of the tangent space $T(M)$. Your formula differs in sign for some reason. Where does it come from?  Are the ${\bf e}_a$ an orthonormal basis, and if so what are the ${\bf e}^a$?  Are they a *coframe*? If so, the sign is right, but they are not the basis vetors of the tansgent space, but rather of its dual $T^*(M)$. Also if this is the case then for a vector $X= X^a {\bf e}_a$ we us  the fact that evalauting a covector on a vector returns its components, i.e. ${\bf e}^a(X)=X^a$, to see that
$$
{\bf e}_a {\bf e}^a(X)= {\bf e}_a X^\mu=X.
$$
Thus $\sum_a {\bf e}_a {\bf e}^a$ is the identity map from $T(M)\to T(M)$. No "$\cdot$" is needed between the ${\bf e}_a$ and the ${\bf e}^a$.

Comment: You are doing a covariant basis while the OP used a contravariant, hence the sign diff.

Comment: @ggcg Yes. That's why I said the sign was correct if he was using a basis for $T^*(M)$ rather than for $T(M)$. It was not clear what the ${\bf e}^a$ were. I usually use the notation ${\bf e}^{*a}$ for the dual basis so as  to avoid the ambiguity of whether  a number $e_1^3$ is the third component of the vctor ${\bf e}_1= e_a^\mu \partial_\mu$ or the first component of the covector ${\bf e}^{*3}= e^{*3}_\mu dx^\mu $.

Comment: I see.  Your previous statement was "for some reason" which kind of made it look like you weren't sure.  Thanks for the reply.